# Mac OS X monitor/observe an app installation

Tags: macos

I would like to monitor an app installation and know what files the app changes, creates and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FSEvents` framework allows applications to register for notifications of changes to a given directory tree. That allows you to track down created, changed or deleted files.

Have a look at the [File System Events Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple.

If you are looking for something existing with GUI: You might want to try [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart)